# Sumar días a una fecha desde inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día, tengo un pequeño dilema. Estoy tratando de calcular la fecha final en donde tengo dos `input` que reciben los valores como `type text`, probé con `Getdate();` para dar formato a la `fecha_inicio` pero si pongo un día mayor a 12 me muestra que es invalida la fecha:

```
function FCalculo_termino()
{       
        var fecha_inicio = $('#TFecha_inicio').val();
        alert(fecha);
        var dias = $('#TNum_diasAfectar').val();
        alert(dias);

}
```

Revisé otros preguntas similares pero no logré solucionar mi problema espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Pero ¿en qué formato se introduce la fecha en el input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo cogiendo la fecha en formato días/mes/año.

Para crear la fecha separa las diferentes partes ejecutando el método `split` y las convierte a número con `parseInt`. Después crea el objeto `Date` pasándole al constructor el año, mes y día.

El número de días se convierte igualmente a número utilizando `parseInt`.

Por último se obtiene el día de la fecha con `getDate`, se suma el número de días y se vuelve a establecer con `setDate`.

```js
function FCalculo_termino()
{       
    var fecha_inicio = $('#TFecha_inicio').val();
    console.log('Fecha', fecha_inicio);
    var dias = $('#TNum_diasAfectar').val();
    console.log('Días', dias);
    
    // Fecha
    // Separar las partes de la fecha por /
    var dateparts = fecha_inicio.split('/').map(d => parseInt(d));
    // Si no hay 3 partes o alguna no es un número no es correcto
    if (dateparts.length !== 3 || !dateparts.every(d => !isNaN(d))){
      $('#Resultado').text('La fecha no tiene un formato correcto');
      return;
    }
    // Crea el objeto Date pasando año, mes, día
    var fechaDate = new Date(dateparts[2], dateparts[1]-1, dateparts[0]);
    
    // Dias en formato entero
    var diasNum = parseInt(dias);
    // Si no es un número no es correcto
    if (isNaN(diasNum)){
      $('#Resultado').text('El número de días no tiene un formato correcto');
    }
    
    // Suma los días a la fecha
    fechaDate.setDate(fechaDate.getDate() + diasNum);
    $('#Resultado').text('El resultado de sumar ' + dias + ' días a la fecha ' + fecha_inicio + ' es ' + fechaDate.toLocaleDateString());
}

$(function(){
  $('#Calcular').click(FCalculo_termino);
});
```

```css
span{
  display: block;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Fecha: <input type="text" id="TFecha_inicio" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" />
Días: <input type="text" id="TNum_diasAfectar" placeholder="Nº de días" />
<button id="Calcular">Calcular</button>
<span id="Resultado"></span>
```

Comment: Todo solucionado, mi problema era no dividir la fecha en partes, por esta razón el primer valor me lo tomaba como meses osea formato mm/dd/yyyy